# jQuery make a copy of HTML and store it for later retrieval

Tags: jquery, clone

I need to be capable to restore the HTML code inside a div as it was at page ready.
I need this because I want to make some changes to the HTML code after page ready and then revert it to the way it was at page ready when I need it..

I was thinking to use clone, but how do I just copy the content of the div without paste it? I need to copy the content of the div at page ready and then paste it/replace the div with the original when I need..

I am rather new to jquery, I tried several things without luck, I can't find out what I need.
Thank you for any suggestion!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode

Comment: `document.documentElement.copy(this).forLater(new Date(now).getTime).change()`. As a sidenote, this sounds like something you would need to do when you've failed at something else ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can copy it into a variable for later.

```
var originalContent;

$(document).ready(function() {
    originalContent = $('#theDiv').clone();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't think of this :)

Comment: Variables do have a limit of number of characters you can save. Since you're working with html which can be quite lengthy it would be safer with session storage.

Comment: Is there any way to pass the variable containing clone through ajax ? i am getting illegal invocation

Comment: @tellmewhy That depends on what you want to do with it on the back end. You should be able to get the html as a string using `originalContent.wrap('<div>').parent().html()`

Comment: How can the complete deep clone be sent through ajax?